# brasero and growisofs fail pointlessly - "space will be wasted"

Tags: iso, dvd, burning, brasero

Trying to burn a copy of Ubuntu 22.04 onto a dual layer DVD, I keep getting this error:

> :-( more than 50% of space will be *wasted*!
> use single layer media for this recording

I don't have any single layer media and I have stacks of double layer media.
How do I get around this complaint?  I do not see any relevant options in either
man page - brasero or growisofs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning that you will waste the space.

If you don't have other disks, then you can ignore the warning.

Comment: There is no option for ignoring the warning - both programs exit after printing it.